# tensorflow - location prediction LSTM/RNN

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have been trying to create a network based on tensor flow learn. 
I have a tuple of x,y locations  - let's say they're the behavior of a very dynamic ghost such as the Pacman game, but the movement is omnidirectional.

I am trying to build a predictor/model based on the previous movement of the object.

I was trying to adapt this example:

https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/master/examples/nlp/dynamic_lstm.py

Example data: 
[[100,67],[94,69]
[88,75],[84,78],[83,80]]

What is the proper network to use and a toy example that would create a predictor?

Comment: What is the question? And what code have you tried?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no question.

Comment: Please provide the code that you have tried.

Comment: See the original question above. The example shows a classification problem. Is this a classification problem? Not sure of the problem space.